# Where to open obscure file types

Tags: ios, animation, 3d

I was given a file of an iOS app to look at, and there were five file types relating to 3D animation that I'd never encountered before: `.sdru`, `.mol`, `.mat` (I assume its materials), `.pvr`, and `.tanim`. Google hasn't told me very much about any of them, and I was wondering if anyone has any knowledge of these file types, or how I can open the files.

Comment: Ask the person that provided you the file. These are obviously proprietary file types and the tools to create them probably don't exist outside of the company that created them.

Comment: @IanMacDonald These files being proprietary would make sense (and be unfortunate). For reference, the person that sent me the files has no relation to the developer, he was hunting through the app, and hoped I could provide some insights. Thanks, anyway.